# .Net interop to Direct Web Remoting (DWR), possible?

Tags: java, .net, interop, dwr

We have an existing code base which is using DWR. I'm wondering what options exist to have .Net clients communicate with the DWR endpoints?

And by .Net I really mean CLR clients, not javascript generated by .Net based websites.

Answer (score 0):

On the client side, dwr is just JavaScript so it should be fine.  As long as you include the needed dwr Ajax scripts from your DWR enabled java servlet container and write your DWR callbacks to interact with the hrml elements that .net creates.

Comment: Sorry - I meant to clarify, by .Net I really mean CLR clients, not .Net generated websites